A question about rational functions in complex analysis
In Ahlfors's complex analysis

$$
R(z)=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}
$$
given as the quotient of two polynomials. We assume, and this is essential, that $P(z)$ and $Q(z)$ have no common factors and hence no common zeros. $R(z)$ will be given the value $\infty$ at the zeros of $Q(z)$. It must therefore be considered as a function with values in the extended plane, and as such it is continuous. The zeros of $Q(z)$ are called poles of $R(z)$, and the order of a pole is by definition equal to the order of the corresponding zero of $Q(z)$.
The derivative
$$
R^{\prime}(z)=\frac{P^{\prime}(z) Q(z)-Q^{\prime}(z) P(z)}{Q(z)^2}
\tag{11}
$$
exists only when $Q(z) \neq 0$. However, as a rational function defined by the right-hand member of (11), $R^{\prime}(z)$ has the same poles as $R(z)$, the order of each pole being increased by one. In case $Q(z)$ has multiple zeros, it should be noticed that the expression (11) does not appear in reduced form.

I can understand these two statements, why the does   the order of each pole being increased by one I can't see why is this true, The second statement I really have no idea what he means.

For the second statement, just try an example.  For instance, $R(z) = \frac{z-1}{z^2}$.  When you use the quotient rule, as shown in $(11)$, do the numerator and denominator have any common factors?

Also note: Use tag{} instead of spacing hacks.  What appears acceptable on your screen may not even be legible on others' screens.  tag{} corrects for this.

For the first statement, you may use the fact that a function $f$ has a pole of order $k$ at $z_0$ iff it can be written (at least locally) as $f(z)=\dfrac{g(z)}{(z-z_0)^k}$ where $g$ is an holomorphic function such that $g(z_0)\neq 0$.
Assuming that $f$ does indeed have a pole of order $k$ at $z_0$, we have $$f'(z)=\dfrac{g'(z)(z-z_0)^k-kg(z)(z-z_0)^{k-1}}{(z-z_0)^{2k}}=\dfrac{g'(z)(z-z_0)-kg(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k+1}}=\dfrac{h(z)}{(z-z_0)^{k+1}}$$ where $h(z)=g'(z)(z-z_0)-kg(z)$ verifies that $h(z_0)=-kg(z_0)\neq 0$.
This means $f'$ has a pole of order $k+1$ at $z_0$.
As for the second statement, if $Q$ has a zero of order at least $2$ at some $z_0$, then $Q(z_0)=Q'(z_0)=0$, and so both the numerator and denominator of (11) have $z_0$ as a common root: this is what the author refers as not in reduced form.

One way, intuitively, to approach this is to write $R$ is terms of partial fractions. If the distinct roots of $Q$ are $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_r,$ witth root $z_i$ having multiplicity $k_i,F then we can write:
$$R(z)=r(z)+\sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^{k_i} \frac{c_{ij}}{(z-z_i)^j}$$ uniquely, where $r(x)$ is a polynomial and $c_{ij}$ are complex constants, and we get that $c_{ik_i}$ is non-zero for each $i.$ Then the derivative gives a new formula:
$$R'(z)=r'(z)+\sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^{k_i}\frac{-jc_{ij}}{(z-z_i)^{j+1}}$$
But that would mean the largest exponent in the denominator for $(z-z_i)$ would be $k_i+1.$
This can be made rigorous by making partial fractions rigorous - proving the partial fractions are unique.
But the process of partial fractions is fairly intuitive if you learned it in calculus.

This is part of a more general notion of pole.
A differentiable function $f$ has a pole of degree $k>0$ at $z_0$ if there $f(z)(z-z_0)^k$ can be made (finite and) differentiable at $z_0,$ but $f(z)(z-z_0)^{k-1}$ cannot.
This turns out to be equivalent to:

There exists $c_1,\dots,c_k$ with $c_k\neq 0$ such that $$f(z)-\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{c_j}{(z-z_0)^j}$$ can be made continuous and differentiable at $z=z_0.$


If $Q(z)$ has a zero of order $k\geq 1$ at $z=a$, then that means we can write $Q(z) = (z-a)^k q(z)$ where $q$ is another polynomial such that $q(a)\neq 0$.
Let's stick this into formula (11), in which we use the product rule to simplify $Q'(z)$:
$$\begin{align*}
R'(z) &= \frac{P'(z)(z-a)^kq(z) - \left[k(z-a)^{k-1}q(z)+(z-a)^kq'(z)\right]P(z)}{(z-a)^{2k}(q(z))^2} \\  \\ 
&= \frac{(z-a)^{k-1}\Big((z-a)\big(P'(z)q(z)-q'(z)P(z)\big) - kq(z)\Big)}{(z-a)^{2k}(q(z))^2} \\ \\ 
&= \frac{(z-a)\big(P'(z)q(z)-q'(z)P(z)\big) - kq(z)}{(z-a)^{k+1}(q(z))^2}
\end{align*}$$
The above can answer both questions.

If we evaluate the numerator at $z=a$, it gives $-kq(a) \neq 0$, so it doesn't have any factor of $(z-a)$.  On a similar note, the denominator, since $(q(a))^2 \neq 0$, has a zero of order $k+1$ at $z=a$.  We conclude $R'(z)$ has a pole of order $k+1$ at $z=a$.
In the last step above, we had to cancel a common factor of $(z-a)^{k-1}$ from the numerator and denominator.  If $k \geq 2$, this factor has degree $\geq 1$, making it a nontrivial common factor.  This means the form $(11)$ gave us for $R'(z)$ is initially not in reduced form.

